# jqGrid fetch Unchecked Checkbox value in hidden field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, jqgrid

**jqGrid structure:**

```
<script>
var call_url = "<?php echo $url;?>";
jQuery("#task-grid").jqGrid({
    url:call_url,
        datatype: "json",
    height: 'auto',
    rowNum: 20,
    rowList: [20,30],
    colNames:['ID','RESOURCE','ROLE','SITE', 'ALLOCATION TYPE', 'UNIT (%)'],
    colModel:[
                {name:'ID',key:true,index:'ID', width:50, align:'center',search:false,hidden: false},
        {name:'RESOURCE',index:'RESOURCE', width:150, sorttype:"text",align:'center',search:true},
        {name:'ROLE',index:'ROLE',width:120 ,align:'center',search:false},
        {name:'SITE',index:'SITE', width:120, align:'center',search:false},
        {name:'ALLOC. TYPE',index:'ALLOCATION_TYPE', align:'center',width:120,search:false },
        {name:'UNIT',index:'UNIT',align:'center',search:false},     
        //{name:'HOURS',index:'HOURS', search:false, align:'center',sortable:false,editable:true}
    ],
    pager: "#page",
    shrinkToFit :true,
    autowidth: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    sortname: 'RESOURCE',
        sortorder: "asc",
        multiselect: true,
        cellEdit: true,
        cellsubmit : 'clientArray',
    caption: "Resource List",

         onSelectRow: function(rowid,iRow,iCol,e){alert(rowid);},

        loadComplete: function (data) {
            var ids = $("#task-grid").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
            for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++){
                var rowId = ids[i];
                $("#task-grid").jqGrid('setSelection', rowId, false);
                //console.log(rowId);
            }
        }
}).navGrid('#page',{ edit:false,add:false,del:false,search:false,cloneToTop:true,refresh:false},
            {

             },{
             //add options

             },{

                        //msg: "do you really want delete this keyword? This delete affect on Eqms filter"

               });


                jQuery("#task-grid").jqGrid('filterToolbar', { autosearch: true  });
        var topPagerDiv = $('#grid_toppager')[0]; 
        jQuery("#grid_toppager_center", topPagerDiv).remove(); 
</script>
```

[image: Checkbox Selected]

[image: Checkbox Unselected]

Code to fetch selected ID's

```
<input type="hidden" name="emp_id_checked" value=""/>
<script>
var Ids = jQuery("#task-grid").jqGrid('getGridParam','selarrrow');
var empIds = $("input[type=hidden][name=emp_id_unchecked]").val(Ids);
</script>
```

I have the `ID (12860)` when checkbox is selected on page load, but how can I pass checkbox value `12860` to hidden input field when its unchecked ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[onSelectRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events#list_of_events) and `onSelectAll` callbacks is the best place to do any additional actions on selection/unselection of rows. The second parameter `status` of the collback inform whether the row/rows will be checked or unchecked.

**UPDATED**: I created [the corresponding demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/UncheckedRows.htm) for you. I placed the list of rowids of unchecked rows inside of visible `<p>` element only to make the results easy to see. I used the following code:

```
multiselect: true,
unselectedRowIds: [], // custom option where we will hold unselected ids
onSelectRow: function (rowid, status) {
    var p = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam"), i = $.inArray(rowid, p.unselectedRowIds);
    //alert("row with id=" + rowid + " is " + (status ? "selected" : "unselected"));
    if (status && i >= 0) {
        // need be removed
        p.unselectedRowIds.splice(i, 1);
    } else if (!status && i < 0) {
        p.unselectedRowIds.push(rowid);
    }

    // update "hidden" control
    $("#unselectedRows").text(p.unselectedRowIds.join(","));
},
onSelectAll: function (rowids, status) {
    var p = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam");

    if (status) {
        p.unselectedRowIds = [];
    } else {
        p.unselectedRowIds = rowids.slice(0); // copy of the array
    }

    // update "hidden" control
    $("#unselectedRows").text(p.unselectedRowIds.join(","));
},
loadComplete: function () {
    $("#cb_" + $.jgrid.jqID(this.id)).click(); // select all rows
}
```

It's important to remark that you should remove unneeded `cellEdit: true` option (the grid don't have any editable column) because the option changes the behavior of row selection.

Comment: How to fetch unchecked checkbox value using `onSelectRow` ?

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy: I don't understand what you mean? If for example the checkbox in the row `12860` will be checked or unchecked then the `onSelectRow` callback will be called with the first parameter `rowid` equal to `"12860"` and the second boolean parameter inform your whether the row will be checked or unckecked. So you need just include your callback `onSelectRow` in jqGrid which you use and do any required actions inside of the callback.

Comment: Could you pls post this with code on how to use `onSelectRow ` and pass that id in hidden input ?

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy: Sorry, but you should post your code which shows how you create jqGrid. You write about some hidden input which have no relation to jqGrid. I hope I will understand you better after I see your code. I will inform you where you can place `onSelectRow` in your code.

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy: I found accidentally that you updated the text of your question. Please write always should comment about it to all which you communicate about the question.

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy: The code which you posted contains many strange parts which can makes problems: 1) you use `cellEdit: true` and even if you don't have any editable columns it change row selection behavior. 2) you use wrong prototype for `onSelectRow`. its parameters should be `rowid, status, e`. 3) selection of **all** rows in `loadComplete` is unclear for me, but if you need that you can do this in one line: `$("#cb_" + $.jgrid.jqID(this.id)).click();`. The options of `colModel` can be reduced without changing the meaning. 4) `name:'ALLOC. TYPE'` should be eliminated. I can comment why.

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy: Now to your main question: Do you just want to get the list (array with ids, comma separated string with ids and so on) of rows which the used unselected? Change `onSelectRow` to the following `onSelectRow: function (rowid, status) { alert("row with id=" + rowid + " is " + (status ? "selected" : "unselected")); }`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. Is it possible to keep the header `checkbox` selected when all the ID's are selected `onSelectAll` ?

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy: You are welcome! Sorry, I don't understand your question. The header of multiselect column is already selected and all rows are selected in [my demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/UncheckedRows.htm).

Comment: `$("#cb_" + $("#task-grid").jqID(this.id)).click();` is not working for me if I have all the ID's selected.

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy: `$("#task-grid").jqID(this.id)` is wrong. You should use `$.jgrid.jqID(this.id)` like in my demo.

Comment: `loadComplete: function (data) {
            //var ids = $("#task-grid").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
            var ids = resource_string.split(',');
            for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++){
                var rowId = ids[i];
                $("#task-grid").jqGrid('setSelection', rowId, false);
            }
        }`. This code keeps the checkbox selected. But if I add `$("#cb_" + $.jgrid.jqID(this.id)).click(); // select all rows` it do not work.

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy: Do you tried [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/UncheckedRows.htm). It uses `loadComplete: function () { $("#cb_" + $.jgrid.jqID(this.id)).click(); }`. Does it work? The code do *the same* what you do in your `loadComplete`. The code is shorter and it works a little more quickly, but if you like your implementation you could hold it. It's independent from your main question. Do you added other callbacks and options to your grid?